# How to switch the subtitle language of Hulu on Apple TV

Tags: appletv, subtitle, hulu

I began watching a show on Hulu. It came up with Spanish subtitles. I want to switch it to English subtitles.

I was instructed by a Hulu customer service rep to go to the Hulu website, log in, pull up the show, start playing it, hover the mouse until the control bar appeared near the bottom of the screen, click the gear, select English from the closed captions options, and then log out on the web site which would set it as a global default. I did this, and it did make the show, as seen on my browser, use English subtitles, but this did not affect the same show as seen on Apple TV. However, if I start watching a new show, the subtitles are in English. It's as though Hulu has "committed" me to watching The Handmaid's Tale with Spanish subtitles, and won't allow it to be changed.

The customer service rep said this was a "known problem with Apple TV" and that I'd have to wait for Apple to fix it. I'm dubious.

Does anyone have experience with the Hulu app on Apple TV, and can suggest how to force a subtitle language change on a series I've already begun watching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i was having the same problem and stumbled on the solution.  While watching the video hit the pause button on the Apple TV controller.  then swipe down.  A menu bar should appear at the top of the paused video Info  Subtitles Audio  When you hover over subtitles you will see it defaulted to Spanish.  Just switch to English.  Wow, so simple but took me forever to accidentally swipe down after pausing and then the menu appeared.  Good luck.

Comment: I've been using the Remote app on my iPhone to control the Apple TV, rather than the controller that came with the Apple TV (I'm not sure you'd "swipe down" with that), but I did as you described - and there it was! Easy enough if you know to swipe down. Many thanks.